# Is "raises question marks over" a correct and common phrase?

Tags: phrases, american-english, british-english

Is a sentence like

> Dynamic method invocation raises question marks over the way
>   existing instances should be handled.

correct in a technical paper (computer science)? (I think it is in the *Economist* data base, so it should be correct.)

I guess *raises questions over the way* is just a lot more common.

If it is correct, is this only common in British English or is it also common in American English? (By the way, I am not a native speaker.)

Comment: Raising question marks sounds wrong in my ears
A good first opinion is here: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raises+questions%2C+raises+question+marks&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Craises%20questions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craises%20question%20marks%3B%2Cc0 another here: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22raises+question+marks%22 (About 116,000 results) vs https://www.google.com/search?q=%22raises+questions%22 (About 1,390,000 results)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree, "raise questions over" sounds better than "raise question marks over" to my British ears.

We can search Google Scholar "to broadly search for scholarly literature" with each phrase.

- ["raises questions over"](http://scholar.google.fi/scholar?q=%22raises%20questions%20over%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) has about 1,940 results.
- ["raises question marks over"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22raises%20question%20marks%20over%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1,5&as_sdtp=) has about 61 results.

Answer (score 3):

"A Question mark over" seems to be veritable idiom according to this source:
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+question+mark+over

It can be used in many ways as in

- "A question mark hangs over something" or
- "This leaves or puts a question mark over something"

It seems to sound off better than "leave **question marks** over something" , at least to me.

Comment: To imply a plurality of problems, I think tweaking the metaphor/idiom is valid. There are certainly examples in what seem to be well-written articles on the internet.